# android service high battery usage

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-wake-lock, repeatingalarm

Have a nice day.
I also am running my application in 60 seconds with a service AlarmManager is.
My problem is this process consumes a lot of battery, how can I solve it?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

***Alarm manager code.***

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            utcMillisNextMin(), 60000, pendingIntent);
    return;
} else {
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            utcMillisNextMin(), 60000, pendingIntent);
    return;
}

public long utcMillisNextMin() {
   Time t = new Time();
   t.setToNow();
   t.second = 0;
   t.minute++;
   return t.normalize(true);
}
```

***AlarmService code.***

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

private WakeLock mWakeLock;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    if (mWakeLock != null && !mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }
    startService();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

private void startService() {
    alarmHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

private Handler alarmHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        rootFonksiyon();  
        //rootFonksiyon in: SharedPreferences are saved when comparing data //and notification to the user.

    if (mWakeLock != null) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
    stopSelf();
    }
};
```

}

```
<service  android:name="---.AlarmService" android:enabled="true" />
```

*Sorry for my bad english*

Comment: Could be that you are not releasing wakelock.

Comment: wakelock release and stopself add.. so that the same problems continue

Comment: I don't see where you release wake lock in your code... Also see if the CPU usage of your service is very high, could be an unwanted infinite loop.

Comment: private Handler alarmHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        rootFonksiyon();  
        //rootFonksiyon in: SharedPreferences are saved when comparing data //and notification to the user.

    if (mWakeLock != null) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
    stopSelf();
    }
};

I use somewhere else?

Comment: Are you shure that is actually being executed?